# Getting 'Invalid or Corrupt jar file' error upon running sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to run sbt but I'm getting this error:

> `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /bin`

This is what I've done so far:

I've placed my `sbt-launch.jar` file inside the `/bin` folder and created a file `sbt` with the following line:

```
java -Xmx512M -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

Then I run `sudo chmod u+x sbt`

Now, when I run `sudo sbt` I get the error.

> `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /bin`

Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It somehow disconnects the `dirname` macro and the concatenation with `/sbt-launch.jar`. Are you sure there is not accidental white space between the two? You could also try to hardcode the path, i.e. use `-jar /bin/sbt-launch.jar`.

Comment: Could you add `echo` before `java`? You could see the full line that's executed and perhaps be able to correct the error afterwards?

Comment: @0__ thats what the problem was. Thanks. Add your comment as an answer and ill mark it correct

Comment: @0__ I know your comment was from a while ago, but thank you because that's exactly what the issue was when I had the same problem as OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It somehow disconnects the `dirname` macro and the concatenation with `/sbt-launch.jar`.

- Make sure there is not an accidental white space between the two
- You could also try to hardcode the path, i.e. use `-jar /bin/sbt-launch.jar`